# Copy image from Application and paste it in Native SMS Application in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i have one Greeting card application in which i have one view as image i want to copy that image and paste it to to native SMS application.

so i need to code for copy image from application.
so i can paste it in SMS Native application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not allow this.  You can do it with plaintext, but not binary data (like an image).

To open the Messages app, you can construct an [`sms://` URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1) and invoke `-[UIApplication openURL:]`, but that's it.

If you'd like this ability to be in a future version of iOS, please [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) and it'll be considered.

Comment: it is possible or not that we can copy the content of view so that we can paste that content to native SMS application because i see one application cartolina card in that application it it possible that paste card in SMS application.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible or not that we can copy the content of view so that we can paste that content to native SMS application because i see one application cartolina card in that application it it possible that paste card in SMS application.